# Sharing i/o between java programs

Tags: java, io, inputstream, outputstream

This question regards the redirection of input and output between two java programs. The source code for a simplified example of my problem is below.

This is prog1:

```
import java.io.*;

public class prog1{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process prog2 = rt.exec("java prog2");
        System.out.println("prog2 has executed.");
    }
}
```

On a separate file, I've written prog2, where I execute Internet Explorer to verify that execution was successful:

```
import java.io.*;

public class prog2{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        System.out.println("You entered " + in.readLine() + ". Starting Explorer...");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
    }
}
```

This is what I see if I run prog2:

```
> java prog2
Enter a string: hello   ** Here the program waited for my input **
You entered hello. Starting Explorer...   ** Here Internet Explorer opens a new window **
```

This is what I see if I run prog1:

```
> java prog1
prog2 has executed.   ** Internet Explorer opens a new window **
```

Note that prog2 did not prompt me for input, and did not output anything. My goal is for the following to occur:

```
> java prog1
Enter a string: hello   ** Here I wish for the program to await my input **
You entered hello. Starting Explorer...   ** Here I wish for an Explorer window to open **
prog2 has executed.
```

I believe that this problem will require a good knowledge of I/O redirection, but I am unfortunately quite unexperienced in that area. Thank you all in advance.

Devin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
Process prog2 = rt.exec("java prog2");
```

With this:

```
Process prog2 = new ProcessBuilder("java", "prog2").inheritIO().start();
```

[ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is the preferred replacement for the Runtime.exec methods.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. Thank you. Now when I run prog1 I see "prog2 has executed." printed to the command line followed by "Enter a string: " on the following line. This is closer to my goal, but not quite there. Is there a recommended way to cause the first program to wait for the termination of the second?

Comment: I found the solution I was looking for. After Process prog2 = new ProcessBuilder("java", "prog2").inheritIO().start(); I added prog2.waitFor(); and a catch for a potential InterruptedException. It works exactly the way I wanted. Thank you again.